# How to reset stop watch for multiple stop watch time?

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to use multiple stop watch timer by using anchor tag.I have successfully done but I am not able to add a functionality like if I clicked first timer,It will start timer from zero,when I clicked second one,first timer's value will be zero and second one will start timer from zero.I am giving my working code below :

JS:

```
var digit=0;
    var hrs = 0;
    var min=0;
    var time;
    var timer_is_on=0;
    var id;

    function timer(id){
        //[Old] - this should be placed after you increment digit
        // document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = digit
        //alert("I am testing value"+id);
        //[New]
        // get the numerical value for seconds,minutes,hours
        digit = parseInt(document.getElementById("secs"+id).innerHTML);
        min   = parseInt(document.getElementById("mins"+id).innerHTML);
        hrs   = parseInt(document.getElementById("hrs"+id).innerHTML);
        // increment;
        digit=digit+1;    


        if(digit>"59"){
            min = parseInt(min)+1;
            // why is this code here
            var count = min.toString().length;
            digit=0;
        }
        // [old] checking if second is greater than 59 and incrementing hours
        // if(digit>"59"){

        // [new] check if minute is greater than 59
        if(min > "59"){
            hrs=parseInt(hrs)+1;        
            digit=0;
            min=0; // minute should be reset as well
        }
         // set the values after all processing is done
        document.getElementById("secs"+id).innerHTML = format(digit);
        document.getElementById("mins"+id).innerHTML= format(min);
        document.getElementById("hrs"+id).innerHTML=format(hrs);
    }

        function activate(id){
        if(!timer_is_on){
            timer_is_on=1;
            // time = setTimeout("timer()",1000) will only call it once , use setInterval instead
            time=setInterval("timer("+id+")",1000);
        }
        else {
            timer_is_on=0;
            clearInterval(time); // clear the timer when the user presses the button again and reset timer_is_on
        }
        return id;
    }

    // left pad zero if it is less than 9
    function format(time){
        if(time > 9)
            return time;
        else return "0"+time;
    }
```

And The HTML code I have used are :

```
<a href="#" onclick="activate(1)">Click here to start the timer</a>
    <span id="hrs1" >00</span>:<span id="mins1" >00</span>:<span id="secs1">00</span></strong>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="activate(2)">Click here to start the timer</a>
    <span id="hrs2" >00</span>:<span id="mins2" >00</span>:<span id="secs2">00</span>
```

Here is my working js fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/EPtFW/1/

Answer (score 0):

as you are using same method activate() to start second timer, it will make first timer as zero if timer already running.

Solution is "you have to maintain multiple unique timer ids for multiple timers"

For Example, let's say you have T1 and T2 timers to start time;

```
var timerMap={};
timerMap[createUniqueId for T1] = setInterval();
timerMap[createUniqueId for T2] = setInterval();

to clear timers
clearInterval(timerMap[createUniqueId for T1]);
clearInterval(timerMap[createUniqueId for T2]);
```

In your case, you have to have createUniqueId and adding to timerMap should be in activate() method. they will work independently.

Comment: I dint understand the code.I am using activate function but I passed a parameter to differentiate it.

Comment: function activate(id) {
 //Stopping...running timer
 if (timerMap[id]) {
  clearInterval(timerMap[id]);
 }
     
 //Start timer...
 timerMap[id] = setInterval("timer(" + id + ")", 1000);
     
 return id;
}

Comment: Here id should be unique, so two timers have to have different ids.